# Why does this redirect fail to load the correct component in my React 18 app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, jsx

I am making a **chat app** with React 18 and Firebase 9.

I run into an issue while working on redirecting a user after a successful registration.

In `App.js` I have:

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  Route,
  RouterProvider,
  Navigate
} from 'react-router-dom';
import RootLayout from './layouts/RootLayout';
import AuthLayout from './layouts/AuthLayout';
import Chat from './pages/Chat';
import Register from './pages/Register';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import { AuthContext } from './contexts/AuthContext';

export default function App() {
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const ProtectedRoute = ({ children }) => {
    if (!currentUser) {
      return <Navigate to="/auth/login" />;
    }
    return children;
  };

  const router = createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(
      <Route path="/" element={<RootLayout />}>
        <Route index
          element={
            <ProtectedRoute>
              <Chat />
            </ProtectedRoute>
          } />
        <Route path="auth" element={<AuthLayout />}>
          <Route path="register" element={<Register />} />
          <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    )
  );

  return <RouterProvider router={ router } />;
}
```

In `src\contexts\AuthContext.js`, I have:

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { auth } from "../firebaseConfig";
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

export const AuthContext = createContext();
export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const unSubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
    });

    return () => {
      unSubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ currentUser }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

In `src\layouts\AuthLayout.jsx`, I have:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import TopBar from '../components/TopBar/TopBar';
import AppFooter from '../components/AppFooter/AppFooter';

export default function AuthLayout() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <TopBar />
      <Outlet />
      <AppFooter />
    </div>
  );
}
```

In `src\layouts\RootLayout.jsx`, I have:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function RootLayout() {
  return (
    <div className='App chat-container'>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}
```

In `Register.jsx` I have:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import md5 from "md5";
import FormCard from "../components/FormCard/FormCard";
import Success from "../components/Alerts/Success";
import Error from "../components/Alerts/Error";
import { make, register } from "simple-body-validator";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, updateProfile } from "firebase/auth";
import { ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { auth, db, storage } from "../firebaseConfig";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";


// Custom validation rule
register('image-only', function (value) {
  let allowedFormats = ["jpg", "jpeg", "png"];
  let format = value.name.split('.')[1].toLowerCase();
  return allowedFormats.includes(format);
}, function () {
  return "Only JPG, JPEG, and PNG files are allowed.";
});

export default function Register() {

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const initialFormData = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    avatar: "",
    password: "",
    password_confirmation: ""
  };

  const validationRules = {
    firstName: ["required", "string", "min:3", "max:255"],
    lastName: ["required", "string", "min:3", "max:255"],
    email: ["required", "email"],
    avatar: ["image-only"],
    password: ["required", "min:6", "confirmed"],
    password_confirmation: ["required"]
  };

  const validator = make(initialFormData, validationRules);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(initialFormData);

  // Form validation errors
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState(validator.errors());
  // Firebase errors
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  const [pristineFields, setPristineFields] = useState(() =>
    Object.keys(initialFormData)
  );

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value, files } = event.target;
    setFormData((prevFormData) => {
      const newValue = files?.length > 0 ? files[0] : value;
      const newFormData = { ...prevFormData, [name]: newValue };
      const newPristineFields = pristineFields.filter((f) => f !== name);

      validator.setData(newFormData).validate();
      const validationErrors = validator.errors();
      newPristineFields.forEach((f) => validationErrors.forget(f));
      setErrors(validationErrors);

      setPristineFields(newPristineFields);

      return newFormData;
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  
    if (!validator.setData(formData).validate()) {
      setErrors(validator.errors());
    } else {
      const email = formData.email;
      const password = formData.password;
      const successContainer = document.getElementById('successAlert');
      const errContainer = document.getElementById('errorAlert');
  
      try {
        const response = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
        // Hide error
        errContainer.classList.add('d-none');
  
        // Show success
        successContainer.classList.remove('d-none');
  
        let userAvatar = "default-avatar.png"; // Default avatar image
  
        // Check if the user uploaded an avatar
        if (formData.avatar) {
          // Create avatar filename
          const meta = { contentType: 'image/jpeg, image/png' };
          const date = new Date().getTime();
          userAvatar = md5(`${formData.email}-${date}`) + '.' + formData.avatar.name.split(".")[1];
  
          const storageRef = ref(storage, userAvatar);
  
          // Upload image
          await uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, formData.avatar, meta);
        }
  
        // Get download URL (either uploaded avatar or default avatar)
        const avatarURL = await getDownloadURL(ref(storage, userAvatar));
  
        try {
          // Update profile
          await updateProfile(response.user, {
            photoURL: avatarURL,
          });
  
          // Store user
          await setDoc(doc(db, "users", response.user.uid), {
            uid: response.user.uid,
            firstName: formData.firstName,
            lastName: formData.lastName,
            email: formData.email,
            avatar: userAvatar,
          });

          // If registration was successful, redirect to the Chat UI
          if (response.user.uid) {
            navigate("/");
          }

        } catch (error) {
          setError(true);
          console.log(error);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        setError(true);
        errContainer.append(error.message);
        errContainer.classList.remove('d-none');
      }
    }
  
    setPristineFields([]);
  };

  return (
    <FormCard title="Register">

      {/* Alerts */}
      <Error dismissible={true} error={error} />
      <Success dismissible={false} message="You have registered successfully!" />

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        
        // Form fields here
        
      </form>
    </FormCard>
  );
}
```

#### The problem

The below code does achieve the desired route change, but it fails to load the `<Chat />` component?

```
if (response.user.uid) {
    navigate("/");
}
```

###### What am I doing wrong?

Comment: “Index routes render into their parent's [Outlet](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet#outlet) at their parent's URL (like a default child route).” - [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#index) Did you place the `<Outlet />` element inside your `RootLayout` component?

Comment: @3limin4t0r Yes, I did place the `<Outlet />`  element inside the `RootLayout`. The app works, except the rendering of the  `<Chat />` component on successful registration. Otherwise, the `<Chat />` is displayed ok.

Comment: Have you tested if `currentUser` in `ProtectedRoute` is updated after a successful registration? You might have forgotten to update the `AuthContext` value.

Comment: Have you utilized the AuthContext.Provider in any part of your application? It's important to note that context API provides values to all its child components. It seems that the issue may arise from the context being undefined whenever you use useContext.

Comment: Hi @RazvanZamfir, I've identified the bug. The createBrowserRouter should be called outside of the React tree. I've fixed it, and you can find the updated code here: [link](https://github.com/ARK-09/stackblitz-starters-9xjppp.git) Please note that I'll remove it in 2 days.

Comment: @KamranSiddique  Post an answer to the present question, with explanations, please, so that more people (myself included) can learn from it. Also, I need an answer to award the BOUNTY to. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue arises because the <kbd>createBrowserRouter</kbd> should be defined outside the React tree. Placing it within the React tree is not the recommended approach. You can verify this by referring to the [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router#:%7E:text=React%20tree%20with%20a%20statically%20defined%20set%20of%20routes).

> createBrowserRouter
>
> This is the recommended router for all React Router web projects. It
> uses the DOM History API to update the URL and manage the history
> stack.
>
> It also enables the v6.4 data APIs like loaders, actions, fetchers and
> more. Due to the decoupling of fetching and rendering in the design of
> the data APIs, you should create your router outside of the React tree
> with a statically defined set of routes. For more information on this
> design, please see the Remixing React Router blog post and the When to
> Fetch conference talk.